# How to check if .NET Framework is installed?

Tags: .net, vb.net

My mission is to check if .NET is installed (and terminate the application if not).

I have to check for the following (we have some application variants)

- FW 3.5
- FW 3.5 SP1
- FW 4.0
- FW 4.5

I guess I have to check if some folder exists - how do I know its name?

Answer (score 2):

This link might be of some use to you: *[How to: Determine Which .NET Framework Versions Are Installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)*

It even has example code for C#, VB.NET, etc...